# Move semantics in Qt without pointers?

Tags: qt, c++11, qt5, move, move-semantics

I have a Qt project, there I have an Object, which is going to be copied a lot of time. Therefor I would like to add move semantics.

```
#ifndef OBJECTTOCOPY_H
#define OBJECTTOCOPY_H

#include <QColor>
#include <QString>
#include <QDataStream>
namespace level_1     {
namespace level_2 {
class ObjectToCopy {
public:

  explicit ObjectToCopy(const QString& _name = "", const QColor& colorBody = QColor() );

  // MOVE
  ObjectToCopy(ObjectToCopy && other);  

  static quint32 _valueInt32;
  static quint16 _valueInt16;
  QString _name;
  QColor  _colorBody;

private:
};
}
}
#endif // OBJECTTOCOPY_H
```

How do I steal the pointers of the member variables, since they are no pointers?

```
ObjectToCopy::ObjectToCopy (ObjectToCopy&& other)
    : _valueInt32( other._valueInt32  )
    , _valueInt16( other._valueInt16 )
    , _name( other._name )
    , _colorBody( other._colorBody )
{
    other._valueInt32 = 0;
    other._valueInt16 = 0;
    other.name.clear();
    other._colorBody = QColor();    
}
```

1. Does that make sense for non-pointers?
2. Is it ok to reset QString 's like string.clear(); to mark that for the garbage collector?
3. How could I reset a QColor object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [std::move](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/move/):

```
ObjectToCopy::ObjectToCopy (ObjectToCopy&& other)
    : _valueInt32( other._valueInt32  )
    , _valueInt16( other._valueInt16 )
    , _name( std::move(other._name) )
    , _colorBody( std::move(other._colorBody) )
{
    other._valueInt32 = 0;            //probably not necessary
    other._valueInt16 = 0;            //probably not necessary
    //other.name.clear();             //not necessary
    //other._colorBody = nullptr;     //not necessary
}
```

1. It makes sense to move non-pointers. You are in the process of making such an object. Moving integers doesn't help, but doesn't hurt either, so you may as well do it for consistancy. Moving things that don't have a move constructor also works: If no move constructor is available the copy constructor is used (moving is not always better, but not worse either).

   The implementation above says "*move by copying the `int`s and moving the `name` and the `_colorBody`*".

   Make sure you do not read from variables you `move`d from.
2. It is ok, but not necessary. `other` is supposed to be a temporary that will get destroyed anyways. (C++ does not have a garbage collector in your sense)

   Also once an object is `move`d from it tends to be in the `clear`ed state like for `QString`, but that is not always the case.
3. You cannot really. You can assign a default constructed one like `other._colorBody = QColor();` but that just means it sets the color to black. A `QColor` cannot be empty, it always has some color.

Also read [What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

You can add move semantics of course, but in your case there is no need in this at all. quint32, quint16 are moved by copying. QColor is wrapper around union and has no move constructor (and doesn't need one) and will also be moved by copying. QString is reference counted type in QT. It has move constructor in recent versions of library, but the difference in speed will be minimal (difference between swapping pointer and incrementing reference counter).